# Proof of continuity?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

> For what values is the following function continuous:
>   $$f(x,y) = \frac{4x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2}$$

The answer is for all $x,y$ such that the denominator isn't zero. Is there a way for me to justify this?

I know that the three conditions for continuity are:

1)The point is in it's domain (we took care of points outside of its domain)
2)The limit exists 
3)The limit is equal to the value of the function

How can I show point 2 and 3? (It doesn't have to be totally rigorous, just a brief explanation of the proof is fine) Thanks!

Comment: A quotient of continuous functions is continuous, on the viable domain

Answer (score 1):

On its domain (that is, where $(x, y) \neq (0, 0)$), the function is a product and composition of continuous functions, and so it is continuous.

It is somewhat more interesting to consider the function $F$ given by $F(x, y) = f(x, y)$ for nonzero $(x, y)$ and $F(0, 0) = 0$. Because $F$ agrees with $f$ away from $(0, 0)$ it is continuous there, but determining whether $F$ is continuous at $(0, 0)$ is slightly more subtle.